# How to Delete / Show a StackLayout through the code behind of my View with MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

You want to hide a StackLayout depending on the value of a property that is evaluated in the constructor, but when hiding it xamarin leaves the blank and does not upload the lower elements upwards, so I will remove the element through code behind (I'm using MVVM)

[image: Example]

But I do not know how to structure my code so that I can evaluate whether or not I eliminate the StackLayout when loading the Vista

In my view I occupy X: Name to identify the element that I want to eliminate or show, after evaluating the condition.

MyView.XAML:

```
        <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"           
                     BindingContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
                     x:Class="AppValora.Views.Sisquim.VerSisquimView">

     <StackLayout       
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="Start">

                    <Image
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Source="{Binding ImageRombo}"                 
                       HeightRequest="160"
                       WidthRequest="160"
                        IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleImagenRombo}">                
                    </Image> 
                    <Image 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Source="cuadro_nch"                  
                        HeightRequest="160"
                       WidthRequest="160">
                     </Image>
                </StackLayout>     

// STACKLAYOUT YOU WANT TO ELIMINATE
         <StackLayout 
            x:Name="StackIsVisible">                
                            <Image 
                                Source="{Binding ImageRomboDos}"                 
                               HeightRequest="160"
                               WidthRequest="160"
                               IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleImagenRombo}">
                            </Image>
            </StackLayout>

        </ContentPage>
```

In my ViewModel, I receive the parameter that I then evaluate in a conditional

MyViewModel.CS:

```
public VerSisquimViewModel(SqsHelper sqsHelper)
        {
           if (sqsHelper.RSEC == null)
            {
                IsVisibleLabelRomboImagenDos = false;
            }        

        }
```

What magic can I do in my Code Behind so that when the condition is met, eliminate the StackLayout and disappear that blank space?

currently I have....

MyView.cs (CODE BEHIND):

```
public partial class MyView : ContentPage
{
    StackLayout hiddenStackLayout;

    public VerSisquimView ()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "");
        StackIsVisible.Children.RemoveAt(1);
        InitializeComponent();

    }

}
```

how can I from the code behind change the value of the property when I start this page?

Is it a bad practice to use code behind with the MVVM pattern?

How can i fix this? any help for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a bad practice to use code behind with the MVVM pattern?

If the code is view related, than it's necessary. Sometimes you just can't avoid code in the code-behind. A Rule to keep in mind, **typically** when you start working with the view, managing things can get to be quite cumbersome. If you find a way to leverage the platform, in this case Xaml, let it do the work for you.

the thing about visibility, the element is rendered on the screen. The user just can't see it. This is why the space is being taken up. Sometimes visibility will work, other times not so much.

In this situation, you can avoid code in code-behind and stick to your VM.

I would suggest using a grid and use a converter to hide a grid row. When I say hide the row, I mean by setting a row's height to 0. So it's rendered but we are going to collapse it. I only added two rows, you can add more to accommodate more content as you see fit.

Edit: added sample namespace. If you are using Visual Studio, there should be intellisense. You have to add the local namespace, so the xaml engine can find the converter class.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"          
                     xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:DataBindingDemos" <-- set the appropriate value
                     BindingContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"                     
                     x:Class="AppValora.Views.Sisquim.VerSisquimView">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <converter:BoolToGridRowVisibilityConverter key="BoolToGridRowVisibilityConverter">
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsStackVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToGridRowVisibilityConverter}}" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <StackLayout   
                    Grid.Row="0"    
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="Start">

                    <Image
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Source="{Binding ImageRombo}"                 
                       HeightRequest="160"
                       WidthRequest="160"
                        IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleImagenRombo}">                
                    </Image> 
                    <Image 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Source="cuadro_nch"                  
                        HeightRequest="160"
                       WidthRequest="160">
                     </Image>
                </StackLayout>     

         <!-- STACKLAYOUT YOU WANT TO ELIMINATE -->
        <StackLayout    Grid.Row="1" 
                        x:Name="StackIsVisible">                
                            <Image 
                                Source="{Binding ImageRomboDos}"                 
                               HeightRequest="160"
                               WidthRequest="160"
                               IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleImagenRombo}">
                            </Image>
            </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Add a converter

```
public class BoolToGridRowVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) : new GridLength(0);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Only one way bindings are supported with this converter");
    }}
}
```

For more information, see a [post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17552/how-to-hide-a-row-or-column-in-a-grid-layout) on Xamarin forums

Comment: What do you mean by setting the appropriate value? , will you have an example of this for me? @Neil

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: I understand that it is the namespace of my ViewModels to occupy its properties and methods

Comment: No, it's the namespace of the converter. where you put it.

Comment: the convert will be implemented in the code behind the same view, what would be the namespace of this? would match the namespace x: Class in this case

Comment: It would be the same namespace as your view, However, I would recommend putting the converter in a separate file. So it's just separate.

Comment: I have implemented the converter in a separate class called ConverterSisquim.cs, but I still fail in the xmlns !! when you put the tag <converter: BoolToGridRowVisibilityConverter Key = "BoolToGridRowVisibilityConverter"> it throws me the error: "The type 'converter: BoolToGridRowVisibilityConverter' Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. AppValora "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181620/discussion-between-neil-and-bodega-pangal).

Answer (score 0):

You can put the IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleImagenRombo}" to the StackIsVisible stacklayout, so that the entire space will be erased.

Comment: it's just what I try to do, but it does not erase the space, it just hides it